# How to get part of the $host variable in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I need to get only part of the $host variable. Domain is in the form img1.**domain.com** and I need to get "domain.com" and then use it in redirect.

I am trying it wrong like this:

```
$host ~* img[0-9]\.(.*);
set $host_without_img $1;
```

I know it would work, if I would put in in IF condition like this:

```
if ($host ~* img[0-9]\.(.*)) {
  set $host_without_img $1;
}
```

But I just don't want to use IF, when it is not necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map), something like this:

```
map $host $host_without_img {
    default ...;
    ~*img[0-9]\.(?<x_host_without_img>.*) $x_host_without_img;
}
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that it will be executed on every request, because it has to be used in http {} context ?

Comment: No. Quote from the linked documentation: _Since variables are evaluated only when they are used, the mere declaration even of a large number of “`map`” variables does not add any extra costs to request processing._